# remove decimal when value is equal 10 else not

Tags: ios, objective-c, decimal

How to remove decimal if value is equal to 10 else decimal value should not removed.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
    if (_ratingValue >= 100) {
        _ratingValue = 10;
        _formatValue = @"%0.0f";
    }
    else{
        _formatValue = @"%.01f";

    }

}

_ratingValue == 0.0f ? [cellProductInfo.view_ProductRating setInnerText:@"review"]        :
[cellProductInfo.view_ProductRating setInnerText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.01f / 10",_ratingValue]];
```

If ratingValue is equal 10, I do not want to show the decimal value else if below 10 want to show decimal value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1 decimal place your format needs to be `%.1f`. For no decimals you want `%.0f`.

If you want values less than 10 to show 1 decimal and values greater or equal to 10 to show none, you want:

```
if (_ratingValue >= 10.0) {
    _formatValue = @"%.0f";
} else {
    _formatValue = @"%.1f";
}
```

Comment: Sorry but your comment is unclear. Did my answer solve your issue or not? If so, please accept the answer. If not, please explain why not.

Comment: The answers for the question solved! I found it in your answer and also in my question too.  :-). Yes you deserves increment count of accept.

Answer (score 0):

```
_ratingValue == 0.0f ? [cellProductInfo.view_ProductRating setInnerText:@"review"]        :
[cellProductInfo.view_ProductRating setInnerText:[NSString stringWithFormat:_formatValue,_ratingValue]];
```

Its works for me!